# Custom Cell in UITablView Not Saving User Input

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have uploaded a quick video of my app in progress

https://vimeo.com/241910642

As you can see, I can add and delete rows in my tableview, as designed, but when it comes to saving the numbers (data) that the user entered, the app keeps calling (null)... I am at a loss... Any ideas? In some of my readings, I am wondering if the custom cell keeps re-writing it's self to "empty"... on viewDidLoad...

Here is some code that may be helpful...

**Creating the cell / row...**

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

SodTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[SodTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}


if(indexPath.row >= tabledata.count && [self isEditing]){

    cell.areaNumber.text = @"new area";


}else{ // this tableview is showing table (not in edit mode)


    cell.areaNumber.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSUserDefaults *save = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [save setObject:tabledata forKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"];
    [save synchronize];
    NSLog(@"This number is from cell creation code %@",[save valueForKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"]);

}

return cell;
}
```

Where **cell.areaNumber.text** is supposed to be the area where the user can input data, when saved to the NSMutableArray **tabledata**. This **IS** saving the creation and deletion of rows but it appears to **NOT** save the data the user input...

So, I wonder if it is my code used to save the data or the code used to display the data when exiting and entering the app...

**Here is a portion of my viewDidLoad...**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"+ / -" style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addORDeleteRows)];[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];


tabledata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if([tabledata count]==0){
    //Your array is empty so you have to call it with @"yourKey"
    tabledata=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"]]mutableCopy];
    // not sure if I need to add "mutableCopy" to end or not

}

numberOfSection = 1;

[myTable reloadData];
```

This is how I am trying to save the data (with a FUTURE intent) of doing something with that data...

```
-(IBAction)save_area:(id)sender {

{
        UITableView *tableView = self.myTable;
        NSInteger sections = tableView.numberOfSections;
        NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  init];
        for (int section = 0; section < sections; section++) {
            NSInteger rows =  [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
                UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];//**here, for those cells not in current screen, cell is nil**
                [cells addObject:cell];

                NSUserDefaults *save1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [save1 setObject:_areaArrayDimension forKey:@"sod_area_input_by_user"];
                [save1 synchronize];
                NSLog(@"This number is from area input %@",[save1 valueForKey:@"sod_area_input_by_user"]);



            }
        }
    }
```

}

You notice I am now saving the new NSMutableArray to _areaArrayDimension as to not overwrite the NSMutableArray used to create, or delete the rows in tabledata. Not sure but the console indicates

```
2017-11-08 12:50:12.309723-0500 landscapepro2[5150:608237] This number is from area input (null)
2017-11-08 12:50:12.309990-0500 landscapepro2[5150:608237] This number is from area input (null)
2017-11-08 12:50:12.310183-0500 landscapepro2[5150:608237] This number is from area input (null)
2017-11-08 12:50:12.310642-0500 landscapepro2[5150:608237] This number is from area input (null)
2017-11-08 12:50:12.311125-0500 landscapepro2[5150:608237] This number is from area input (null)
```

Sorry for the lengthy quesiton, but I am stuck on the item and once this is figured out, I will need to do something with those numbers once saved.

Thanks for taking the time to review...

Comment: you can implement the textfield/textview delegate methods, and when you enter data into the field, these delegates methods gets called, and you can save the data based on the textfield cell row.

Comment: Thanks... I do have those delegates in this line of code...`@interface SodTry : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

Answer (score 0):

So almost solved... I was able to save a value in the UITextField and save it to the array, and show it... however, if you look at the video here [on vimeo showing the result](https://vimeo.com/241990900)

You'll notice the behaviour I am referring too.  It only saves the LAST VALUE of the last row in the table and then when it returns from view it appears in the first row of the table... I must need to include some "extra piece" that says "add me to the next row in the array" :) I think it might have to do with my code in **textFieldDidChange** (see below) You can also look at my console for reference in the video... Here is the code that saves the values using textFieldDidChange...

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField
{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
[tabledata removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tabledata insertObject:theTextField.text atIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

And here is the code that shows the values

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

SodTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[SodTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

//if number of rows is greater than the total number of rows in the data set and this view is in editing mode.
//Initialize the cell for "Add Row"
//there will be an extra row once SetEditing: is called
if(indexPath.row >= tabledata.count && [self isEditing]){

    cell.areaNumber.text = @"new area";


}else{ // this tableview is showing table (not in edit mode)

    //Using your data source array to get your data for each cell
    //[cell addSubview:cell.areaNumber];

    [cell.areaNumber addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    cell.areaNumber.delegate = self;

    cell.areaNumber.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(SodTableCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

// Configure the cell...
UILabel*label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2.5, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];

NSString*text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Area %ld",(long)indexPath.row+1];
[label setText:text];
[label setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.41 green:0.33 blue:0.25 alpha:1.0]];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:14.0f];
[cell.contentView addSubview: label];

NSUserDefaults *save1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[save1 setObject:tabledata forKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"];
[save1 synchronize];
NSLog(@"This number is from cell configuration %@",[save1 valueForKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"]);
}
```

I have also created a button to save all the numbers in this code...

```
-(IBAction)save_area:(id)sender {

{
        UITableView *tableView = self.myTable;
        NSInteger sections = tableView.numberOfSections;
        NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  init];
        for (int section = 0; section < sections; section++) {
            NSInteger rows =  [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
                UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];//**here, for those cells not in current screen, cell is nil**
                [cells addObject:cell];

//                    SodTableCell *cell2 = (SodTableCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//                    cell2.areaNumber.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                NSUserDefaults *save1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [save1 setObject:tabledata forKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"];
                [save1 synchronize];
                NSLog(@"This number is from save button %@",[save1 valueForKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"]);

            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

Here is the code used with my "save" button action... Basically I needed to identify the custom cell as part of the function...

```
-(IBAction)save_area:(id)sender {

{
        UITableView *tableView = self.myTable;
        NSInteger sections = tableView.numberOfSections;
        NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  init];
        for (int section = 0; section < sections; section++) {
            NSInteger rows =  [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
                UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];//**here, for those cells not in current screen, cell is nil**
                [cells addObject:cell];

                SodTableCell *cell2 = (SodTableCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                [tabledata removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [tabledata insertObject:cell2.areaNumber.text atIndex:indexPath.row];

                NSUserDefaults *save1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [save1 setObject:tabledata forKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"];
                [save1 synchronize];
                NSLog(@"This number is from save button %@",[save1 valueForKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```